# Is it safe to install Rust crates? Is `crates.io` curated or reviewed for malware?

Tags: security, rust, rust-cargo, malware, rust-crates

With Debian and Ubuntu, there is some quality control. With `Boost` (C++'s main repo), there is [significant](https://www.boost.org/community/reviews.html) quality control. Are Rust `crates(.io)` similar or are they a complete free-for-all? Can anyone upload any code they want under any name that they want?

`crates.io`'s "Security" link sends you to `rust-lang.org/policies/security` that just talks about how very important security is to Rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not safe by default. [Lib.rs](https://lib.rs) is integrated with review systems, though. If you check [a crate](https://lib.rs/crates/bitflags), there will be <kbd>Audit</kbd> button, leading to the [reviews list](https://lib.rs/crates/bitflags/audit).

[image] [image]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the [cargo.io policies](https://crates.io/policies) page gives you the answer you are looking for:

> Removal
>
> Many questions are specialized instances of a more general form: “Under what circumstances can a package be removed from Crates.io?”
>
> The short version is that packages are first-come, first-served, and we won’t attempt to get into policing what exactly makes a legitimate package. We will do what the law requires us to do, and address flagrant violations of the Rust Code of Conduct.

Since they are not policing valid packages that implicitly means they are not reviewing packages uploaded to crates.io.

Answer (score 2):

Crates.io does not review packages before publishing them.

This is not unusual. Most package repositories, including NPM, PyPi (the repo behind pip), and Ruby gems don't do any auditing before publishing. It's simply too much work to do for free and slows publishing down a lot. The downsides to this are well known, and there are plenty of articles describing them and instances of problematic behavior (ex. left-pad).

Boost is different in that it curates libraries before inclusion. That elevates the trust and helps ensure good practices, but gives the repository much less breadth - you won't, for example, find a QUIC client in Boost.

Comment: What if a C++ person who never used Ruby/JS/Python/etc. is starting to use Rust? Would he not have the expectation that someone is  reviewing the packages, especially given all the talk about "security is super-important to us" and no flashing warnings? Boost is not unique BTW. I just listed one of each to illustrate that there are different approaches.

Comment: @MWB This isn't really the place to argue the merits of a curated list over an open registry. Your question has been answered: it is not curated. There is a list on [blessed.rs](https://blessed.rs/crates) that may suit your needs. And if you discover a malicious crate, you can report it and it will be removed. See the [Rust Blog](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/05/10/malicious-crate-rustdecimal.html) on one such case.

Comment: @MWB Stack Overflow is not the place to complain. It's off topic and the crates.io maintainers are not going to read this. Your question has been answered - take your commentary to your blog.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Comments are meant to improve the answers, as is mine. You are claiming in your answer that users should already have the expectation that repository packages are a free-for-all, and there is no need for `crates.io` to explicitly warn them. That's incorrect.

Comment: @MWB I said it was _not unusual_, and listed several examples. I could add more - D's dub and luarocks for example. The fact that your (or anyone else's) expectations do not match reality does not change the answer. What style of curation these repos _should_ do is a matter of opinion.

Comment: You said *"Boost is somewhat unique"*, which it of course isn't. There are big, free software repos that are curated. But again, I'm not arguing that `crates.io` should review its packages (which it probably should though). Whether it has a duty to warn the users is more of a `law.SE` question, so I'll leave that also. I'm just saying your answer is **factually** incorrect, and that's why I'm not accepting it.

Comment: `Boost` and `crates.io` are not really comparable. `Boost` contains about [171 libraries](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/?view=condensed), while `crates.io` has over 130000!

Comment: @rodrigo They are very comparable in the sense that if you need, say, serialization, or much of the other commonly used, but not `std` functionality, you'll probably reach for `Boost` and `crates.io` respectively, depending on your language.